# Как вставить фон (картинку) в элементы маркированного списка, адрес на которые прописан в соседнем маркированном списке

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть два маркированных списка. У одного в атрибутах `data-img`элементов `li` прописаны `url`ы картинок, которые должны стать фоном у элементов второго маркированного списка.
написал вот такой код, думал что он перебегает корректно, но похоже при каждом проходе он обращается к первому элементу `li`

```js
$(".views").each(function() {
  var bg = $(this).attr("data-img");
  //alert(bg);

  $("ol.buttons li a").css({
    background: "url(" + bg + ")"
  })
})
```

```css
.views {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 2px;
  background: #ccc;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  /* Убираем маркеры */
}
li.but {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}
ol.buttons {
  text-align: center;
}
a {
  background-size: cover!important;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="parent-view">
  <li class="views" data-img="http://goodimg.ru/img/tsvetochek-risunok3.jpg"></li>
  <li class="views" data-img="http://agu-shop.ru/images/pink_flower_512x512.png"></li>
  <li class="views" data-img="http://www.raskraska.ru/counting/flower-bw.gif"></li>
</ul>
<ol class="buttons">
  <li class="but"><a>1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="but"><a>2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="but"><a>3</a>
  </li>
</ol>
```

знаю, что еще и `for` есть, но как все это перебрать не могу понять...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так как индексы совпадают, а вставляете в фон в ссылки, то и бежать можно ао ссылкам используя [функцию css](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function)

```
$("ol.buttons li a").css('background', function(index) {
  return 'url(' + $(".views:eq(" + index + ")").data('img') + ')';
});
```

В функции которая вызывается для конкретной ссылки и должна вернуть значение свойства просто выбирается соответствующий элемент с классом `.views` и берется его нужное значение.

Пример:

```js
$("ol.buttons li a").css('background', function(index) {
  return 'url(' + $(".views:eq(" + index + ")").data('img') + ')';
});
```

```css
.views {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 2px;
  background: #ccc;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  /* Убираем маркеры */
}
li.but {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}
ol.buttons {
  text-align: center;
}
a {
  background-size: cover!important;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="parent-view">
  <li class="views" data-img="http://goodimg.ru/img/tsvetochek-risunok3.jpg"></li>
  <li class="views" data-img="http://agu-shop.ru/images/pink_flower_512x512.png"></li>
  <li class="views" data-img="http://www.raskraska.ru/counting/flower-bw.gif"></li>
</ul>
<ol class="buttons">
  <li class="but"><a>1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="but"><a>2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="but"><a>3</a>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: $(".views:eq(" + index + ")").data('img') - вот этот момент только человеческим языком прочитать не получается а так все работает, благодарю!)

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов, здесь собирается строка формата: `$(".views:eq(0)").data('img')`, `$(".views:eq(1)").data('img')`, `$(".views:eq(2)").data('img')` и т.д. просто вместо цифры текущий индекс элемента подставляется