# Как вставить блок во все элементы маркированного списка, и присвоить каждому фон (картинку) адрес на которую указан в соседнем

Tags: javascript, jquery

Перебрались все элементы списка, но блоки вставились в первый тег `а`.
Во втором случае, каждый фон вставил в свой блок - тут все нормально. 
Как можно вставить эти блоки `.orbit` на свои места и перебрать многоуровневый список с помощью each?
хотя наверное будет достаточно просто их раскидать по своим родителям.

```js
$("ol.flex-control-nav li").each(function() {

  var parr = document.querySelector("ol.flex-control-nav li a");
  var block = document.createElement('div');
  block.className = 'orbit';
  parr.appendChild(block);


});


$(".backround").each(function(i) {
  var bg = $(this).attr("data-img");
  $("ol.flex-control-nav li a .orbit").eq(i).css({
    background: "url(" + bg + ")"
  })
});
```

```css
 .backround {
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
   width: 30%;
   height: 50px;
   margin: 2px;
   background: #ccc;
 }
 li {
   list-style-type: none;
   /* Убираем маркеры */
 }
 li.but {
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
   margin: 5px;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   border: 1px solid red;
   text-align: center;
 }
 ol.flex-control-nav {
   text-align: center;
 }
 a {
   background-size: cover!important;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   display: block;
   position: relative;
 }
 .orbit {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   width: 25px;
   height: 25px;
   background-size: cover!important;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="parent-view">
  <li class="backround" data-img="http://goodimg.ru/img/tsvetochek-risunok3.jpg"></li>
  <li class="backround" data-img="http://agu-shop.ru/images/pink_flower_512x512.png"></li>
  <li class="backround" data-img="http://www.raskraska.ru/counting/flower-bw.gif"></li>
</ul>
<ol class="flex-control-nav">
  <li class="but"><a>1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="but"><a>2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="but"><a>3</a>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вставить фон (картинку) в элементы маркированного списка, адрес на которые прописан в соседнем маркированном списке](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/495928/)

Comment: так нет,так все проще было, а теперь усложнил, и запутался...

Comment: в чем ключевое отличие? и почему используются `querySelector`, `createElement` и т.д. а не jQuery функции?

Comment: отличается тем что теперь пробую внутри еще и блоки создать к которым прикреплю фон, и проблема то теперь другая получилась, не в установке фона в том что блоки у первого родителя создались, а ответ на второй вопрос простой - учусь, не знаю как лучше. Столько информации в голове сразу

Comment: ну и ещк просто мало знаю, каким образом можно блоки создавать и присваивать им классы, посмотрел видеоуроки, там немного вариантов описывается, среди которых например не было того, что указан в ответе ниже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы пишите `document.querySelector("ol.flex-control-nav li a");` то результатом данной выборки будет один первый элемент, а не как в jquery несколько.

Не используйте такие длинные констуркции `ol.flex-control-nav li a .orbit`, если у вас `orbit` применяется только в этом кусочке верстки страницы, то так и пишите `.orbit`.

```js
$(function(){
  
  $("ol.flex-control-nav li a").each(function(i,el) {

  $(this).append('<div class="orbit"></div>');


});


$(".backround").each(function(i) {
  var bg = $(this).attr("data-img");
   $("ol.flex-control-nav li a .orbit").eq(i).css({
    background: "url(" + bg + ")"
  });
});
  
});
```

```css
.backround {
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
   width: 30%;
   height: 50px;
   margin: 2px;
   background: #ccc;
 }
 li {
   list-style-type: none;
   /* Убираем маркеры */
 }
 li.but {
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
   margin: 5px;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   border: 1px solid red;
   text-align: center;
 }
 ol.flex-control-nav {
   text-align: center;
 }
 a {
   background-size: cover!important;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   display: block;
   position: relative;
 }
 .orbit {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   width: 25px;
   height: 25px;
   background-size: cover!important;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="parent-view">
  <li class="backround" data-img="http://goodimg.ru/img/tsvetochek-risunok3.jpg"></li>
  <li class="backround" data-img="http://agu-shop.ru/images/pink_flower_512x512.png"></li>
  <li class="backround" data-img="http://www.raskraska.ru/counting/flower-bw.gif"></li>
</ul>
<ol class="flex-control-nav">
  <li class="but"><a>1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="but"><a>2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="but"><a>3</a>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Благодарю! можете только объяснить зачем в первой строчке через запятую el прописан?

Comment: удалите параметры да и все.

Answer (score 1):

Единственное отличие от [соседнего вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/495928/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF) в том, что тут нужно у коллекции вызывать метод [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/#append-function) внутри которого создавать элемент и сразу присваивать ему класс/стиль

```js
$("ol.flex-control-nav li a").append(function(index) {

  return $('<div></div>').addClass('orbit').css('background', 'url('+$('.backround:eq('+index+')').data('img')+')');

});
```

```css
.backround {
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
   width: 30%;
   height: 50px;
   margin: 2px;
   background: #ccc;
 }
 li {
   list-style-type: none;
   /* Убираем маркеры */
 }
 li.but {
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
   margin: 5px;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   border: 1px solid red;
   text-align: center;
 }
 ol.flex-control-nav {
   text-align: center;
 }
 a {
   background-size: cover!important;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   display: block;
   position: relative;
 }
 .orbit {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   width: 25px;
   height: 25px;
   background-size: cover!important;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="parent-view">
  <li class="backround" data-img="http://goodimg.ru/img/tsvetochek-risunok3.jpg"></li>
  <li class="backround" data-img="http://agu-shop.ru/images/pink_flower_512x512.png"></li>
  <li class="backround" data-img="http://www.raskraska.ru/counting/flower-bw.gif"></li>
</ul>
<ol class="flex-control-nav">
  <li class="but"><a>1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="but"><a>2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="but"><a>3</a>
  </li>
</ol>
```